# Decryption and emacs client

Tags: emacsclient, epa

I started using `(server-start)` recently and only using emacs client (with `-c -a emacs` option). The expected behavior when opening a .gpg file is that epa automatically tries to decrypt the file but for some reason emacs client only gets to see the gibberish I would see with say geddit without any error message at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: what happens when you do the same in a plain Emacs session (not a client)?

Comment: It decrypts the file automatically.

Comment: Are you using gnupg? Which version? Do you use environment variables to set up gnupg? Is there any difference between environment variables in a terminal and environment variables in Emacs?

Comment: gpg2 and it is recognized by default. For some reason I updated pdf-tools and when running `pdf-tools-install` it got fixed...